# Writing the following javascript code without repeating myself

Tags: javascript, code-formatting

First of all PhpStorm is telling me that my selector is duplicated, which is true (first and last line are concerning the same selector), and secondly, I just feel that this is some ugly piece of code but I really don't see how can I make it look better. I was thinking of doing a toggle kind of thing for the two last lines, but I can't figure out. Can someone help me ? Thanks

```
if ($('#jstag_product_yes').is(":checked")) {
    $('#price_currency_div').hide();
}

$('#jstag_product_no').click(function () {
    $('#price_currency_div').show();
});

$('#jstag_product_yes').click(function () {
    $('#price_currency_div').hide();
});
```

Comment: Save it in a variable: `var $product_yes = $('#jstag_product_yes'); if ( $product_yes.is(':checked') {} $product_yes.click();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent duplicate selectors save the `jQuery` objects in variables:

```
const $productYes = $('#jstag_product_yes');
const $productNo = $('#jstag_product_no');
const $priceCurrencyDiv = $('#price_currency_div');

if ($productYes.is(":checked")) {
    $priceCurrencyDiv.hide();
}

$productNo.click(function () {
    $priceCurrencyDiv.show();
});

$productYes.click(function () {
    $priceCurrencyDiv.hide();
});
```

Assuming `#jstag_product_yes` is a radio input, if you want to use a toggle you can do the following:

```js
const $priceCurrencyDiv = $( "#price_currency_div" );

$( "#jstag_product_yes" ).on( "change", function() {

    if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
        $priceCurrencyDiv.hide();
        return;
    }

    $priceCurrencyDiv.show();

}).trigger( "change" );
```

Because I chained `.trigger("change")` it will be triggered on load. So no need for your first `.is(":checked")` anymore!!

Comment: Oooh man this was that simple I didn't think of it that way, thanks !

Comment: Have you any idea how to make that part better looking though ??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by better looking? I don't think it necessarily looks bad. If you want to use a toggle you should add the HTML to your question. That way I can think about a better solution for you

Comment: I added an example for using a toggle to the question @DevMoutarde

Comment: Thanks man !! actually this might look even worse lol. I dont know, I thought my code was not so elegant... but it ll do the trick. Thank you again :)

Comment: @DevMoutarde It might look worse but it's 1/3 shorter. 8 instead of 12 lines of actual code. Only 1 variable declaration and no duplicate selectors ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the result of that jQuery selection into a variable and use use that variable instead. That should make PhpStorm happy.

```
let priceCurrencyDiv = $('#price_currency_div');

if ($('#jstag_product_yes').is(":checked")) {
    priceCurrencyDiv.hide();
}
```

This can be done for all the jQuery selections you repeat.

Comment: thanks a lot man, Im upvoting you but voting for jrswgtr answer since its a liiiittle bit more detailled and accurate... trying to be fair on SO is a pain . Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution fits you. I added variables for the elements and reusable functions to control the div:

```
const productYes = $('#jstag_product_yes');
const productNo = $('#jstag_product_no');
const priceCurrency = $('#price_currency_div')

if (productYes.is(":checked") {
  hidePriceCurrency()
}

productNo.click(showPriceCurrency);
productYes.click(hidePriceCurrency);

function hidePriceCurrency() {
  priceCurrency.hide();
}

function showPriceCurrency() {
  priceCurrency.show();
}
```